# How to pull the array object from the MYSQL Dev Api in express?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to pull out the object/array myResults and I've tried as many methods as I can to pull this out but am unable to, can someone please help?

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');


router.post('/email/:email', function (req, res, next){


let p_email = req.params.email
console.log (p_email)


mysqlx
.getSession( {

    user: 'user', 
    password: 'password',
    host: 'localhost', 
    port: '33060', 
})
.then(function(session) {

    const oracleDb = session.getSchema('nms2019local');

    var myTable = oracleDb.getTable('operators');


 myTable
         .select (['email','password', 'admin'])
         .where('email like :email')
         .bind('email', p_email)
         .execute(function (row) {
            console.log(row);
            const foundEmail = row[0]
            const password = row[1]
            const admin = row[2]
            const myResults = {
             foundEmail: foundEmail, 
             password: password, 
             admin: admin  }
            console.log(myResults);
            return (myResults, console.log(myResults));
            })    
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            })
            return (myResults)






}) 





res.send('Oracle5 is here');

});


module.exports = router;
```

This is what nodemon shows:

```
test@email.com
POST /oracle5/email/test@email.com 200 14.621 ms - 15
[
  'test@email.com',
  'password',
  1
]
{
  foundEmail: 'test@email',
  password: 'password',
  admin: 1
}
[
  {
    getWarnings: [Function: getWarnings],
    getWarningsCount: [Function: getWarningsCount],
    fetchAll: [Function: fetchAll],
    fetchOne: [Function: fetchOne],
    getColumns: [Function: getColumns],
    getResults: [Function: getResults],
    nextResult: [Function: nextResult],
    toArray: [Function: toArray]
  }
```

It is probably something really simple but I've tried several iterations and just can't get the right combination to get the array out as an object.   Also there is a .this() function that seems like it would be the best for what I'm trying to do but the documentation is horrid so if please give some information on that function as well it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Need more clarification. What you are trying to achieve??

Comment: Where is your code which extracts array from the result??

Answer (score 0):

You are using what I like to call a push-based cursor, where you provide a callback when calling `execute()`.

This is useful for making sure that data not buffered at the driver/connector level. However, it uses a weird pattern and as soon as you want to buffer the result set at the application level, it requires you to keep track of multiple contexts, the one from the callback you provide (called whenever a row of the result set becomes available), and the one within the `then()` handler (called once the operation finishes) and share state between those contexts to make sure you have consistent results.

In this case, you can, for instance, declare a variable accessible in the scope of both contexts that will keep that shared state. That state is populated while processing the result set, and the final state can be returned back whenever the operation finishes.

```
mysqlx.getSession({ user: 'user', password: 'password', host: 'localhost', port: '33060' })
  .then(function (session) {
    const oracleDb = session.getSchema('nms2019local');
    const myTable = oracleDb.getTable('operators');

    // the variable should be accessible within the callback and the `then()` handler
    const myResults = [];

    myTable.select(['email', 'password', 'admin'])
      .where('email like :email')
      .bind('email', p_email)
      .execute(function (row) {
        // populate the state
        myResults.push({ foundEmail: row[0], password: row[1], admin: row[2] });
      })
      .then(() => {
        // return the final state
        return next(myResults);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

I'm not sure about which version of the connector you are using, but since 8.0.18, you have an alternative (and probably more reasonable) interface. You can drop the callback provided to `execute()` and the client will automatically switch to a pull-based cursor mode, accessible in the `then()` handler. Which does not require to keep track of any state or context.

So, in that case, you can now have something like:

```
mysqlx.getSession({ user: 'user', password: 'password', host: 'localhost', port: '33060' })
  .then(function (session) {
    const oracleDb = session.getSchema('nms2019local');
    const myTable = oracleDb.getTable('operators');

    myTable.select(['email', 'password', 'admin'])
      .where('email like :email')
      .bind('email', p_email)
      .execute()
      .then(res => {
        const myResults = res.fetchAll()
          .map(function (row) { 
            return { foundEmail: row[0], password: row[1], admin: row[2] };
          });
        return next(myResults);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

Disclaimer: I'm the lead dev of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector/Node.js

Comment: thank you for the quick response,  just for clarification whats the difference in this case between fetch.one vs fetch.all, does fetch one just pull one of the array elements or would it not matter if I used fetch.one vs fetch.all in this case?

Comment: `fetchOne()` reads one argument from the current result set. So, if you want to read the entire result set, you can use it as an iterator like `while (var doc = res.fetchOne()) { /* do something */ }`. Since it reads only one element, in the case of a document it returns back a plain JavaScript Object. `fetchAll()` reads the entire result set at once, so it returns a JavaScript Array containing one or more of those objects.

Comment: Great follow up, so I'm able to return and send the results and they get authenticated, however it does send a 500 response code whether it finds the row/email or not, my next question would be how can I send a 200 response code if the search finds the email address, or a 400 response if the function does not find the email address?

Comment: That's a bit off-topic and I'm not really an `express` or REST service expert. In your case, seems like you want something like a 404 (Not Found) instead. So you, can simply use an `if` statement to check if the list is empty `if (myResults.length === 0) { res.status(404).send('some message') } else { res.send(myResults) }`.